# Android 5.1.1 SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: android, ssl

it is giving this SSLhandshakeException. When app run on Android5.1 (android versions >= 4.4)it gives the exception. I tested it on Android 4.3, it works fine. What could be the cause of this ? Please help

```
W/System.err(14221): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
W/System.err(14221):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:390)
W/System.err(14221):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.waitForHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:623)
W/System.err(14221):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:585)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.<init>(SocketInputBuffer.java:75)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:88)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(DefaultClientConnection.java:175)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.bind(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:111)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.openCompleted(DefaultClientConnection.java:134)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:768)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:700)
W/System.err(14221):    at com.up.testjavasdkdemo.ssltest.HttpHandler.makeRequestWithRetries(HttpHandler.java:75)
W/System.err(14221):    at com.up.testjavasdkdemo.ssltest.HttpHandler.doInBackground(HttpHandler.java:132)
W/System.err(14221):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
W/System.err(14221):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err(14221):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err(14221):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err(14221):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W/System.err(14221): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb7c985b0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
W/System.err(14221): error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:770 0xae157cc5:0x00000000)
W/System.err(14221):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
W/System.err(14221):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:318)
W/System.err(14221):    ... 20 more
I/SSLTest (14221): onFailure:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed  strMsg:Handshake failed
W/System.err(14221): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
W/System.err(14221):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:390)
W/System.err(14221):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.waitForHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:623)
W/System.err(14221):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:585)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.<init>(SocketInputBuffer.java:75)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:88)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(DefaultClientConnection.java:175)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.bind(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:111)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.openCompleted(DefaultClientConnection.java:134)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:768)
W/System.err(14221):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:700)
W/System.err(14221):    at com.up.testjavasdkdemo.ssltest.HttpHandler.makeRequestWithRetries(HttpHandler.java:75)
W/System.err(14221):    at com.up.testjavasdkdemo.ssltest.HttpHandler.doInBackground(HttpHandler.java:132)
W/System.err(14221):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
W/System.err(14221):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err(14221):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err(14221):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err(14221):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W/System.err(14221): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb7c985b0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
W/System.err(14221): error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:770 0xae157cc5:0x00000000)
W/System.err(14221):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
W/System.err(14221):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:318)
W/System.err(14221):    ... 20 more
```

Comment: Could you format your question and post here your code?

Comment: @Dima Kozhevin. Yes, I made a custom socketFactory class called SSLSocketFactoryEx.java

Comment: Ho,ho,ho.I have fixed this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Use this class like this while connecting :

public void httpEX(Context context) throws Exception {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore  
                    .getDefaultType());  
            trustStore.load(null, null);  

            SSLSocketFactory sf= new SSLSocketFactoryEx(context, trustStore);   

        BasicHttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();

        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(httpParams, socketTimeout);
        ConnManagerParams.setMaxConnectionsPerRoute(httpParams, new ConnPerRouteBean(maxConnections));
        ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(httpParams, 10);

        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, socketTimeout);
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, socketTimeout);
        HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParams, true);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(httpParams, DEFAULT_SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE);

        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(httpParams, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));
        ThreadSafeClientConnManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParams, schemeRegistry);
        httpContext = new SyncBasicHttpContext(new BasicHttpContext());



        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, httpParams);

        httpClient.addRequestInterceptor(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
            public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) {
                if (!request.containsHeader(HEADER_ACCEPT_ENCODING)) {
                    request.addHeader(HEADER_ACCEPT_ENCODING, ENCODING_GZIP);
                }
                for (String header : clientHeaderMap.keySet()) {
                    request.addHeader(header, clientHeaderMap.get(header));
                }
            }
        });

        httpClient.addResponseInterceptor(new HttpResponseInterceptor() {
            public void process(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
                final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (entity == null) {
                    return;
                }
                final Header encoding = entity.getContentEncoding();
                if (encoding != null) {
                    for (HeaderElement element : encoding.getElements()) {
                        if (element.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(ENCODING_GZIP)) {
                            response.setEntity(new InflatingEntity(response.getEntity()));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        clientHeaderMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ho,ho,ho.I have fixed this question.Android 5.1 default disable SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 cipher suites.
I need chang SSLSocketFactoryEx.java class, implement the method:                                                                       `    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,
            boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException { 
        SSLSocket S = (SSLSocket) sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);

```
    String[] availableCiphers =S.getEnabledCipherSuites();
    for (String cipherSuite : availableCiphers) {
        logwarn("cipherSuite ====c========== " + cipherSuite);
      }
    List<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < availableCiphers.length; i++)
    {
        aa.add(availableCiphers[i]);
    }
    aa.add("SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5");
    aa.add("TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV");
    String[] m_ciphers = aa.toArray(new String[0]);
    logwarn("new ====preferredCiphers========== " + m_ciphers.length);
    S.setEnabledCipherSuites(m_ciphers);
    return S;
    }`
```

Answer (score -1):

```
I made a custom socketFactory class called SSLSocketFactoryEx.java

import com.android.org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;
import com.pos.hsm.PKCS11Wrapper;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import Decoder.BASE64Decoder;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
//import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
public class SSLSocketFactoryEx extends SSLSocketFactory {      
    private static final String[] TLS_SUPPORT_VERSION = {"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"};//Android 5.1 default enable SSLv3

    SSLContext sslContext =SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    public SSLSocketFactoryEx(final Context context, KeyStore truststore)      
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException,      
            KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        TrustManager trustManager = new X509TrustManager() {

            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                logwarn("alias =========getAcceptedIssuers===== ");
                return new X509Certificate[0];      
            }      

            @Override      
            public void checkClientTrusted(      
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)      
                    throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
                logwarn("=====================checkServerTrusted===================");
                if(chain != null)logwarn("length = " + chain.length);
                try {
                    CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                    X509Certificate cert = null;
                    X509Certificate ca;
                    ByteArrayInputStream bais;

                    if(chain != null && chain.length > 0){
                        bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(chain[0].getEncoded());
                        cert = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(bais);
                        bais.close();
                    } else {
                        throw new CertificateException("There is no certificate");
                    }
                    byte[] trust = RSASignature.readFileByBytes(context, "trust01.crt");
                    logwarn("trust cert = " + new String(trust));
                    bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(trust);
                    CertificateFactory myCertificateFactory;
                    ca = (X509Certificate)factory.generateCertificate(bais);
                    bais.close();
                    cert.verify(ca.getPublicKey());
                }catch (Exception e){
                    logwarn("TrustManager checkServerTrusted failed!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw new CertificateException(e);
                }
            }

            @Override      
            public void checkServerTrusted(      
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)      
                    throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {      
                logwarn("=====================checkServerTrusted===================");
                if(chain != null)logwarn("length = " + chain.length);
                try {
                    CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                    X509Certificate cert = null;
                    X509Certificate ca;
                    ByteArrayInputStream bais;
                    if(chain != null && chain.length > 0){
                        bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(chain[0].getEncoded());
                        cert = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(bais);
                        bais.close();
                    } else {
                        throw new CertificateException("There is no certificate");
                    }
                    byte[] trust =  RSASignature.readFileByBytes(context, "trust01.crt");
                    logwarn("trust cert = " + new String(trust));
                    bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(trust);
                    CertificateFactory myCertificateFactory;
                    ca = (X509Certificate)factory.generateCertificate(bais);
                    bais.close();
                    cert.verify(ca.getPublicKey());
                }catch (Exception e){
                    logwarn("TrustManager checkServerTrusted failed!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw new CertificateException(e);
                }
            }      
        };
        X509KeyManager keyManager = new X509KeyManager() {
            @Override
            public String chooseClientAlias(String[] keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket) {

                logwarn("=====================chooseClientAlias===================");
                if(keyType != null && keyType.length > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < keyType.length; i++){
                        logwarn("keyType["+i+"]=" + keyType[i]);
                    }
                }
                if(issuers != null && issuers.length > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < issuers.length; i++){
                        logwarn("issuers["+i+"]=" + issuers[i].getName());
                    }
                }
                return "pk2048";
            }

            @Override
            public String chooseServerAlias(String keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket) {
                logwarn("=====================chooseServerAlias===================");
                logwarn("keyType================" + keyType);
                if(issuers != null && issuers.length > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < issuers.length; i++){
                        logwarn("issuers["+i+"]=" + issuers[i].getName());
                    }
                }
                return "trust01";
            }

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String alias) {
                logwarn("=====================getCertificateChain===================");
                logwarn("alias ============== " + alias);
                byte[] publickey = RSASignature.readFileByBytes(context, "client2048.crt");
                InputStream ceris = new ByteArrayInputStream(publickey);
                CertificateFactory myCertificateFactory;
                try {
                    myCertificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                    X509Certificate cer = (X509Certificate)myCertificateFactory.generateCertificate(ceris);
                    ceris.close();
                    return new X509Certificate[]{cer};
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }

            @Override
            public String[] getClientAliases(String keyType, Principal[] issuers) {
                logwarn("=====================getClientAliases===================");
                logwarn("keyType================" + keyType);
                if(issuers != null && issuers.length > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < issuers.length; i++){
                        logwarn("issuers["+i+"]=" + issuers[i].getName());
                    }
                }
                return new String[0];
            }

            @Override
            public String[] getServerAliases(String keyType, Principal[] issuers) {
                logwarn("=====================getServerAliases===================");
                logwarn("keyType================" + keyType);
                if(issuers != null && issuers.length > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < issuers.length; i++){
                        logwarn("issuers["+i+"]=" + issuers[i].getName());
                    }
                }
                return new String[0];
            }

            @Override
            public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String alias) {
                logwarn("=====================getPrivateKey===================");
                logwarn("alias ============== " + alias);
                byte[] keyData = RSASignature.readFileByBytes(context, alias + ".crt");
                String keyString = new String(keyData);
                keyString = keyString.replaceAll("\n", "");
                Pattern pattern =Pattern.compile("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----(.*?)-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");
                Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(keyString);
                while (matcher.find()) {
                    keyData = matcher.group(1).getBytes();
                }
                try {
                    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(keyData));//PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(keyData));
                    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA","BC");
                    PrivateKey privateK = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);
                    return privateK;
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        //sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
        sslContext.init(new KeyManager[]{keyManager}, new TrustManager[]{trustManager}, null);

    }      

    @Override      
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,      
            boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException { 
        //injectHostname(socket, host);
        SSLSocket S = (SSLSocket) sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
        String[] enProtocols = S.getEnabledProtocols();
        for (String cipherSuite : enProtocols) {
            logwarn("enProtocols ====c========== " + cipherSuite);
          }
        String[] Protocols = S.getSupportedProtocols();
        for (String cipherSuite : Protocols) {
            logwarn("Protocols ====c========== " + cipherSuite);
          }
        S.setEnabledProtocols(TLS_SUPPORT_VERSION);
         enProtocols = S.getEnabledProtocols();
        for (String cipherSuite : enProtocols) {
            logwarn("enProtocols ====en========== " + cipherSuite);
          }
        Protocols = S.getSupportedProtocols();
        for (String cipherSuite : Protocols) {
            logwarn("Protocols ====add========== " + cipherSuite);
          }
        String[] original =S.getEnabledCipherSuites();
        for (String cipherSuite : original) {
            logwarn("cipherSuite ====c========== " + cipherSuite);
          }
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port,      
                autoClose);      
    }      
    private void injectHostname(Socket socket, String host) {
        try {
            Field field = InetAddress.class.getDeclaredField("hostName");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(socket.getInetAddress(), host);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            ignored.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override      
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        SSLSocket S = (SSLSocket) sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
        S.setEnabledProtocols(TLS_SUPPORT_VERSION);
        String[] original =S.getEnabledCipherSuites();
        for (String cipherSuite : original) {
            logwarn("cipherSuite ============== " + cipherSuite);
          }
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();      
    }
    void logwarn(String msg) {
        Log.d("AndroidSSLSocketFactory", msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is an answer to your question than show what is the relevant part to fix the problem instead of just dumping a pile of code. If this instead are additional information to the question then include these in the question. But note that the question will probably be quickly dismissed if you just dump a pile of code - instead make a [__Minimal__, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).